# Call node route from inside same application

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Let's say I have a nodejs application that exposes a route:

```
app.get('/something/resource', function(req, res) { // ... });
```

The route is available both for the public and for the application itself. I want from the same application to call this route inside a function and handle it's response.
The closest way I got to this is using request module:

```
request(req.headers.host + '/something/resource', function(err,res,body) { //... });
```

However the error I am getting is "Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1'"

If I don't use the host header I get "Invalid URI '/something/resource"

Any idea how I can access the application's api from within?

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid Protocol" might mean that it is missing the protocol specifier (some "http://") in front of the URL so try:

```
request("http://" + req.headers.host + '/something/resource', function(err,res,body) { //... });
```

Also two more points:
As host you could hard-code it to "localhost", i'd expect. And keep the port in mind: often, node.js is called to listen on other ports (than default http port 80). So better add the port to the url:

```
request("http://" + req.host + ":" + req.port + '/something/resource', function(err,res,body) { //... });
```